# How to test whether WinHttpRequest works or if corporate security issue causes error

Tags: vba, excel, http

I found the following code on an excel forum:

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

I see no reason why it would not work if I use a legitiamte URL. I have been testing it and keep on getting a FALSE returned. Opening the same URL in a browser works.

I suspect that this might have something to do with our coporate security settings. **How can I test whether the code works or if it is a security issue?**

The function goes to the error line on `.Send`

Comment: Your completely ignoring errors, comment out the on-error handler & see what happens.

Comment: Ok. It produces Run Time Error -2147012867(80072efd). "A connection with the server could not be established" Would this mean that my request is not even leaving my network?

Comment: According to this article it is the firewall: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/831685/connection-to-the-server-cannot-be-established-error-message-when-you I guess that answers my question! Thank you for your help... please leave it as an answer and I can give you credit for it!